# Static Content with Spring

Tags: css, spring, model-view-controller

I'm using

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

To handle static content in my SpringMVC app. This works fine. I am able to upload images and retrieve them within the application using the "/resources" url .I want to use an jpeg for a background image in a jsp, so I though I would simply drop the jpeg into the resources folder in my workspace. However, there is no resource folder in my workspace folder anywhere. Where is spring storing these images? How do I get to this folder to add my background image?

as requested web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-    app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SpringMVCTest</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springMVCTest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springMVCTest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

servlet.xml to clarify everything is configured properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<context:component-scan base-package="/"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" p:maxUploadSize="1000000" />

<bean id="personService" class="PersonServiceImpl" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="/" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

The call to the save image method

```
saveImage(context.getRealPath("/resources/" + person.getId() + ".jpg"), image);
```

Comment: can you post your `web.xml`?

Comment: Sure, but why? all it contains is the mapping for the dispatcher servlet.

Comment: wanted to make sure you didn't have a resources servlet definition there

Answer (score 0):

> However, there is no resource folder in my workspace folder anywhere

It should be present in WebContent. If its not there then `<mvc:resource>` is not being used to serve static content.

> How do I get to this folder to add my background image?

Create resources folder under WebContent and put your images into it. Access the images by `/resources/foo.jpeg`.

Comment: If it is not being using how is spring accessing the images i'm uploading in my web app? I did try adding a resources folder in this location but it did not make a difference.

Comment: Spring dont decide where you keep the *uploaded* images. Its completely upto you/code to decide where to store the images. IMO uploaded images will be store in db.

Comment: right and I'm using saveImage(context.getRealPath("/resources/" + person.getId() + ".jpg"), image); to save them to the resources folder  so they can be accessed by my jsp's. But the resources folder does not exits in my workspace folder.

Comment: This might help http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't say anything about the location of the resources folder in the fie system.

Comment: @user1584500: It do containa example which says `to serve resource requests with a URL pattern of /resources/** from a public-resources directory within the web application root..`. Just folder name differs.

Comment: Well, ok, but that's just saying that the files should be in a folder called "resources" in my web application root. Which isn't there.